# ignore value $request == null

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table

```
| id|lvl1_name  |lvl2_name|lvl3_name  |value
| 1 |Fruit      |Apple    | USA       |20
| 2 |Fruit      |Apple    | England   |30
| 3 |Fruit      |Manggo   | USA       |45
| 4 |Fruit      |Manggo   | England   |15
| 5 |vegetable  |Spinach  | USA       |20
| 6 |vegetable  |Spinach  | England   |30
```

This is my controller:

```
$parameters_id = Fruits::where('lvl1_name', $request->lvl1)
            ->where('lvl2_name', $lvl2)
            ->select('id')->pluck('id');
```

If my request:
`$request->lvl1 = "Fruit"` and `$request->lvl2 = "Apple"`
will show all apple

my question is
if my request
`$request->lvl1 = "Fruit"` and `$request->lvl2 = null`

How to show all "Fruit" without select option on `lvl2`?

Comment: try `WhereNull('lvl2_name')` instead of `where`

Comment: not working @Dr.Strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when` to only run a `where` statement if a variable is set.

```
$parameters_id = Fruits::where('lvl1_name', $request->lvl1)
    ->when($lvl2, function($query, $lvl2) {
        $query->where('lvl2_name', $lvl2);
    })
    ->select('id')->pluck('id');
```

It's available under https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses

> Sometimes you may want clauses to apply to a query only when something else is true. For instance you may only want to apply a where statement if a given input value is present on the incoming request.